# Flex- weird highlighting for custom search component

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I have a custom component which is used to filter data on the screen as the user types in it.  This component is used inside a ResizableTitleWindow (another custom component extending from TitleWindow). When this ResizableTitleWindow is maximzed, the highlighting is perfect.

The problem is- when the ResizableTitleWindow is restored to default size and the user clicks on this component, the area above the component gets highlighted instead of the component border getting highlighted...

This is the code for the Custom search component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:HBox
xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"   
verticalScrollPolicy="off" horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
verticalAlign="middle" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
width="100" borderStyle="inset" initialize="init()"
implements="com.hillelcoren.components.autoComplete.interfaces.iComboItem"
xmlns:classes="com.hillelcoren.components.autoComplete.classes.*" horizontalGap="0">
<mx:Image source="assets/searchImg.png" maxHeight="20" minWidth="15"/>  
<mx:Metadata>
    [Event(name="change")]
    [Style(name="promptColor", type="uint", format="Color", inherit="yes")]
</mx:Metadata>

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.core.Application;
        import mx.core.UIComponent;
        import mx.containers.Box;
        import mx.controls.Image;
        import mx.states.SetStyle;

        private var _prompt:String;
        private var _promptChanged:Boolean;

        private var _isPromptSet:Boolean;
        private var _drawFocusBorder:Boolean = true;

        [Bindable]
        private var _enableClearIcon:Boolean = true;
        private var _enablePrompt:Boolean = true;
        private var _isMouseOver:Boolean;

        private var _text:String;
        private var _textChanged:Boolean;

        private var _promptColor:String;
        private var _textPadding:int = 10;

        [Bindable]
        public var displayAsPassword:Boolean;

        private function init():void
        {
            addEventListener( FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, handleFocusIn );
            addEventListener( FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT, handleFocusOut );
            addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, handleMouseOver );
            addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, handleMouseOut );

            textInput.addEventListener( Event.CHANGE, handleChange );               

            _promptColor = getStyle( "promptColor" ) ? getStyle( "promptColor" ) : Consts.COLOR_TEXT_DISABLED;              
        }

        override protected function commitProperties():void
        {
            super.commitProperties();

            if (_textChanged)
            {
                _textChanged = false;
                setNewText();
            }

            if (_promptChanged)
            {
                _promptChanged = false;

                if (!_text) 
                {
                    showPrompt();
                }
            }
        }                       

        override public function styleChanged( styleProp:String ):void 
        {
            super.styleChanged( styleProp );

            if (!styleProp || styleProp=="promptColor") 
            {
                _promptColor = getStyle( "promptColor" ) ? getStyle( "promptColor" ) : Consts.COLOR_TEXT_DISABLED;

                if (_isPromptSet)
                {
                    setStyle( "color", _promptColor );
                }
            }
        }

        private function showPrompt():void
        {
            if (_prompt == null || !_enablePrompt)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (!textInput)
            {
                return;
            }

            // check that the component isn't currently focused
            var focus:InteractiveObject = textInput.getFocus();

            if (focus && focus.parent == textInput)
            {
                return;
            }

            _isPromptSet = true;
            textInput.text = _prompt;

            setStyle( "color", _promptColor );
            setStyle( "fontStyle", "italic" );
        }

        private function hidePrompt():void
        {
            if (_isPromptSet)
            {
                textInput.text = "";    
            }

            _isPromptSet = false;

            clearStyle( "color" );
            clearStyle( "fontStyle" );
        }

        public function set textPadding( value:int ):void
        {
            _textPadding = value;
        }

        override public function get minWidth():Number
        {
            return measureText( text ).width + _textPadding;
        }

        public function set prompt( value:String ):void
        {
            _prompt = value;
            _promptChanged = true;

            invalidateProperties();
        }

        public function set enableClearIcon( value:Boolean ):void
        {
            _enableClearIcon = value;
        }

        public function set enablePrompt( value:Boolean ):void
        {
            _enablePrompt = value;

            if (!_enablePrompt)
            {
                hidePrompt();
            }
        }

        override public function validateNow():void
        {
            super.validateNow();

            textInput.validateNow();
        }

        public function get text():String
        {
            if (_isPromptSet)
            {
                return "";
            }
            else
            {
                // When setting the htmlText property there's a delay until the text
                // property is ready. This will force it to update it's text value 
                if (textInput.text == null && textInput.htmlText != null)
                {
                    validateNow();
                }

                return textInput.text;
            }
        }

        public function get selectionBeginIndex():int
        {
            return textInput.selectionBeginIndex;
        }

        public function set text( value:String ):void
        {
            _text = value;
            _textChanged = true;

            invalidateProperties();
        }

        private function setNewText():void
        {   
            if (_text == null)
            {
                textInput.text = "";
                textInput.setSelection( 0, 0 );

                showPrompt();
                hideClearIcon();
            }   
            else
            {
                hidePrompt();
                textInput.text = _text;                         
            }

            textInput.validateNow();
        }

        public function setTextSelected( value:Boolean ):void
        {
            var startPos:uint = value ? 0 : text.length;

            textInput.setSelection( startPos, text.length );
        }

        private function handleFocusIn( event:FocusEvent ):void
        {
            if (_drawFocusBorder)
            {
                drawFocus( true );                  
            }

            if (_isPromptSet)
            {
                hidePrompt();
            }
        }

        private function handleFocusOut( event:FocusEvent ):void
        {
            if (_drawFocusBorder)
            {
                drawFocus( false );
            }

            if (textInput.text.length == 0)
            {
                showPrompt();
            }
        }

        public function set drawFocusBorder( value:Boolean ):void
        {
            _drawFocusBorder = value;
        }

        private function handleChange( event:Event ):void
        {
            dispatchEvent( event );

            // this helps keep the input at a good 
            // horizontal scroll position
            var scrollPos:int       = textInput.horizontalScrollPosition;
            var maxScrollPos:int    = textInput.maxHorizontalScrollPosition;

            if (scrollPos - maxScrollPos > 50)
            {
                textInput.horizontalScrollPosition -= 50;
            }

            if (_isMouseOver)
            {
                if (text && text.length > 0)
                {
                    showClearIcon();
                }
                else
                {
                    hideClearIcon();
                }
            }                                                                       
        }

        private function handleMouseOver( event:MouseEvent ):void
        {
            _isMouseOver = true;

            if (text.length == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            showClearIcon();
        }

        private function handleMouseOut( event:MouseEvent ):void
        {
            _isMouseOver = false;

            /*
            if (clearIcon.visible = true)
            {
                if (event.relatedObject == getChildAt(1))
                {
                    return;
                }                   

                hideClearIcon();
            }
            */

            hideClearIcon();
        }

        private function hideClearIcon():void
        {
            clearIcon.visible = false;
        }

        private function showClearIcon():void
        {
            if (_enableClearIcon)
            {
                clearIcon.visible = true;
            }                                                                           
        }

        private function handleClearClick():void
        {
            text = null;
            validateNow();
            textInput.text = null;
            hidePrompt();
            setFocus();

            textInput.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP));
        }

        override public function setFocus():void
        {
            textInput.setFocus();
        }   

        public function get item():Object
        {
            return null;    
        }                       

        public function isEditable():Boolean
        {
            return true;    
        }       

        public function setTextFocus():void
        {
            textInput.setSelection( 0, 0 );
            setFocus();
        }   

        public function isCursorAtBeginning():Boolean
        {
            return selectionBeginIndex == 0;
        }               

        public function isCursorAtEnd():Boolean
        {
            return selectionBeginIndex == text.length;
        }

        public function setCursorPosition( value:int ):void
        {
            _setCursorPosition( value );
            callLater( _setCursorPosition, [value] );
        }   

        private function _setCursorPosition( value:int ):void
        {
            textInput.selectionBeginIndex = value;
            textInput.selectionEndIndex = value;
        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<classes:ShorterTextInput id="textInput" width="100%" borderStyle="none" displayAsPassword="{ displayAsPassword }"/> 
<mx:Image id="clearIcon" source="@Embed('/com/hillelcoren/assets/icons/clear.png')" verticalAlign="middle" 
    visible="false" includeInLayout="{ _enableClearIcon }" click="handleClearClick()"/>
</mx:HBox>
```

Any help in this context will be appreciated !!

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 1):

I finally find a solution for this problem. It'll maybe help someone.
This problem appears with a custom radio, a custom toolbar or any other custom button.
The solution is to add (focusAlpha = "0").

Hope it'll help.